# Is it possible to use hibernate criteria and run SQL directly?

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

I'm having performance problems with `org.hibernate.Criteria`, because I'm fetching too many rows from the data base to populate my primefaces datatable.

I have successfully solved this problem for other tables in my system by using `org.hibernate.SQLQuery` and building my entities my self.

But in this particular case, I do not want to stop using criteria because there are a lot of filters and ordering in the table that's already implemented with `Criteria`...

So my question is... is it possible to get my `Criteria` object, with all the restrictions and orders that I set, and instead of using `myCriteria.list();`, use something else that runs just the SQL from this `Criteria` and returns something like the `org.hibernate.Query.list()` where I could construct the entities my self?

THanks!!

Comment: Why don't you use projections and select exactly what you want to select? You don't need SQL to do that. http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch17.html#querycriteria-projection

Comment: Think about query pagination (Query's setFirstResult, setMaxResults) if it fits to your requirements. Providing pagination mechanism (+ajax is even better) to huge table is always plus.

Comment: @JBNizet, thanks for the suggestion. The problem is that in my entities, I have some columns that are not real columns, they are annotated with `@Formula`... can I use them with projections?

Comment: @nigi, thanks but I need to show at least 10000 rows, that's the problem.. or else I would use lazy pagination